# How to rewrite interval $[1, \infty)$ as a union of intervals in R

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers, interval-arithmetic

I am trying to rewrite interval $[1, \infty)$ as a union of intervals in R. My attempt is $[1, \infty) = \bigcup [1, n) \space $ for $n >1. $ Is that correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, for that matter, $[1,\infty)$ itself is an interval.

Comment: Sure, that's fine. Every number in $[1, \infty)$ appears in at least one of the intervals $[1,n)$, hence $[1, \infty) \subseteq \bigcup [1,n)$. Conversely, if $x$ is in $\bigcup [1,n)$ then $x$ is in some $[1,n)$, hence also in $[1,\infty)$. For fun, you can modify your example to $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[n,n+1)$ to obtain a **disjoint** union that equals $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: Are you using $n$ to represent a natural number?